# How do we deal with outdated meta Questions?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I've seen a lot of Q&A on meta.SO which are hopelessly outdated. If they are precious (EG, historical significance), how about a big note on top of them **outdated! here's something newer that might be related**, or something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I favor deletion in this case, unless there is something exceptionally valuable to capture in the discussion.

Although, I suspect at least one user quit the network over my propensity for deleting what I believe to be outdated information on meta, so -- opinions vary.

Either way, PLEASE flag such things for mod attention. I will look at them!

Comment: Or create a red "Outdated" tag, so you have no hard time deciding if deletion is fair

Comment: @beli outdated flag is too far down to be seen. By the time users see it, their minds have been poisoned by out of date, incorrect, obsolete, useless information.

Comment: So, perhaps it's time to think about a semi-semantic tag structure instead of a plain one. Accepting synonymic tags (VB = Visual Basic = MS-VBA = Microsoft Visual Basic) and tree -multiple hierarchical - tag structures (Least Squares son of Numerical Methods son of Math, but also Least Squares son of Statistics) may improve the tag concept. Preventing being accused of being naive, I solemnly declare: _It's not easy_ :)  Just feed for thought